# Nonlinear constraints with fmincon in matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-optimization

I am using fmincon to minimize overlap between circles over a map region. This is working for the rectangle/square region however I would like to have the constraint that the centers of the circles are on land (the continental US). Is there a way to specify this constraint in fmincon using inpolygon?

Answer (score 0):

No, because that would introduce non-smoothness in your optimization problem. Deciding if a point is in a polygon is a yes/no decision.

However, you can always rewrite the polygon constraint, with `x` the vector of optimization variables as `Ax<=b`. A 2D example, with `x=[x1;x2]` and assuming a square region, the values would be

```
A = [1 0; -1 0; 0 1; 0 -1];
b = [1; 0; 1; 0];
```

Comment: What does b represent here?

Comment: right but how did you come up with A and b for this example? are x1,x2 2 points or is x1=x and x2=y?

Comment: yeah, x1=x, x2=y indeed